# Android OverlayItem.setMarker(): Change the marker for one item

Tags: java, android, android-maps

Trying to change the marker from an overlay item I noticed the setMarker() makes the item not visible. Here's the code sample.

```
//Create new marker
Drawable icon = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);

//Set the new marker to the overlay
overlayItem.setMarker(icon);
```

Comment: have you found a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue. calling setMarker() with a specific drawable makes the icon invisible...

Comment: You have to specify the bounding rectangle using `setBounds()`

Comment: that indeed works, you should answer the question ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A bounding rectangle needs to be specified for the Drawable:

```
//Create new marker
Drawable icon = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);

//Set the bounding for the drawable
icon.setBounds(
    0 - icon.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2, 0 - icon.getIntrinsicHeight(), 
    icon.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2, 0);

//Set the new marker to the overlay
overlayItem.setMarker(icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work:

```
public void addOverlay(final OverlayItem overlay)
    {
        creditOverlay.add(overlay);
        populate();
        boundCenter(customMarker);
    }
```

You will have to call `boundCenter` or `boundCenterBottom` while adding overlay in map overlay list. In `SetMarker()` just set the custom maker.

Comment: This will cause all the items to use the same marker, unless the method is changed to: `addOverlay(OverlayItem, Drawable)