# Spinner visibility in android 4.0

Tags: android, spinner

working on an app in which the screen background is "#232323"(almost black), i have spinners on the screen, the problem is that the spinner marker(at bottom right corner) is not visible in android 4.0 device as the screen background and the marker color is similar. Is there any way to change the spinner marker color?
Looking forward for your help... 
Thank you :)

Comment: You could draw the marker icon.. Look at this, maybe could help you: [icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505574/android-overlayitem-setmarker-change-the-marker-for-one-item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your spinner it will change your spinner colour.

```
mdt_spn=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.xmdtm_spn);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,mdt_arr) {

        public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            ((TextView) v).setTextSize(30);
            ((TextView) v).setTextColor(
                    getResources()
                    .getColorStateList(R.color.mycolor1));
            return v;
        }

        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView,
                    parent);

            ((TextView) v).setTextSize(35);
            ((TextView) v).setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(
                    R.color.mycolor));


            return v;
        }
    };
mdt_spn.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Comment: it's changing only text color of spinner.